# Don't want TeXstudio save all the open files as work on one file

Tags: texstudio

I am working on a particular file in TeXstudio, meanwhile I need to look through some other Tex files. I have noticed every time I compile my file, all the other open files get saved. I don't want to save any possible changes to those files, just to be sure they have remained intact. How can I turn this off?

Comment: In case you don't find a solution in texstudio, you can, as a workaround, use your operating system and tempoarily make the files read only . This can even be done from the texstudio menu `file->fifix->Set permissions...`

Comment: Not possible at the moment, I think. It's hardcoded into the source code -- everytime you run a command (even `view-pdf`), `fileSaveAll()` is executed. This is worthy of a [feature request to the devs](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues), in my opinion.

Comment: I considered a solution with compiling via command line in TeXstudio (through a macro, for e.g.). It works (i.e., the other documents are not saved), but in order to view the result in the internal PDF viewer, you still need to run `txs:///view-pdf` which triggers a `fileSaveall` nevertheless.

Comment: @Troy, on my linux version of txs, if the internal viewer is open then it refreshes the pdf after compiling from terminal, for example. And other opened files are not saved. So, the idea is to don't click on view pdf, but simply keep it opened.

Comment: @Sigur Oh yeah, you're right. Guess I didn't try hard enough. :p I still don't think it's a satisfactory solution, however. Regarding @samcarter's suggestion, you can right click on the file name tab and choose `Set Read-only`

Comment: @Troy, my tab has no such option.

Answer (score 1):

I use Textudio 2.12.8 in Windows (spanish installation), you can configure the document as read only by right clicking on the corresponding tab and displaying the options in which set-read only is found, then it appears with a padlock; I have not checked it because I usually want the opposite function, that is, everything is saved; Another solution is to use another editor as [atom](https://atom.io/) for example to visualize the files, if you have 2 monitors, of course ...

[image]

Comment: The read-only method doesn't work for me: Say `A.tex` is the working file, and `B.tex` is the 'other file'. Make changes to both so they are both unsaved. Set `B.tex` to read-only, then compile `A.tex` (or just `File->Save All`). Unset read-only for `B.tex`, and it is no longer unsaved.